# How can I display links between tags in XML to be a string value in my UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing, rss, uitextview

I'm new for Swift programming.

I am using the below XML parsing codes to display RSS Feeds. Actually, the code works that I want. But I can not solve a problem.

I callback the "description","title" and "pubDate" tags from XML url. The text between the "description" tags of the RSS url that I use, displays the details of that news. Already that's what I want. But, in a different RSS url(shared below), There are summary information in the "description" tags and the URL of that news details in the "link" tags. I need string value that in the content of this URL. But for I can see this content, I need to click this URL link.

But I want to display the news detail text,  automatically, within in the TextView that I created without clicking on any link. Because I will use this string value, for another process.

I invastigated this topic how can I do but I couldn't find.

If you have an solution, could you share with me with little example codes?

I hope that I explained clearly what I wanted.

The example XML files screenshots are as below.

[current URL http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mghcy.png)

[The news detail is in url link http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/rss.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtHm7.png)

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ParseRSSFeeds: XMLParser, XMLParserDelegate{
     var parser = XMLParser()
var news: [Dictionary<String, String>]! = Array()
var elements: [String:String]! = Dictionary()
var element = String()
var header = String()
var link = String()
var desc = String()
var date = String()

func parseFromUrl(){

    news = []
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")! as URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()


}
```

}

```
extension ParseRSSFeeds {
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    element = elementName

    if (elementName) .isEqual("item") {

        elements = Dictionary()
        elements = [:]
        header = String()
        header = ""
        link = String()
        link = ""
        desc = String()
        desc = ""
        date = String()
        date = ""

    }
}


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    if element .isEqual("title"){

        header = header + string

    }else if element .isEqual("link"){

        link = link + string

    }else if element .isEqual("description"){

        desc = desc + string

    }else if element .isEqual("pubDate") {

        date = date + string

    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if (elementName) .isEqual("item") {

        if !header .isEqual(nil) {

            elements["title"] = header
        }
        if !link .isEqual(nil) {

            elements["link"] = link
        }
        if !desc .isEqual(nil) {

            elements["description"] = desc
        }
        if !date .isEqual(nil) {

            elements["pubDate"] = date
        }

        news.append(elements)
        print(news)


    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you writing Swift code like Objective-C?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What does your comment means? @rmaddy

Comment: You are using Objective-C data types. Don't use any of those `NSxxx` classes. Use Swift `String`. Use Swift dictionaries and Swift arrays.

Comment: Thank you I can change but, Is it answer of my question? I can not found a relationship between your response and your response.

Comment: Update your code so it is written using Swift types and then it will be much easier to help you solve your question. At the moment all of your code needs to be fixed so it's difficult to focus on the question you are asking.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated the codes.